# Login failed: error Error Could not send Message. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException

Tags: juddi

I am unable to login through JUDDI user interface. Using newly created publisher. This is the error I am facing.

```
Login failed: error Error Could not send Message. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException.
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please check your backend server.Is it working proerly.@Pradeep Kumar

Comment: hi experts. I am able to use the JUDDI-GUI now. I have registered a service using (Register Services from WSDL). now I want to export the wsdl from JUDDI as a client. I am able to get the service , tmodel, binding template information. how to generate the wsdl file from these?